# Are any JavaScript engines tail call (TCO) optimized?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, tail-recursion

I have a tail recursive pathfinding algorithm that I've implemented in JavaScript and would like to know if any (all?) browsers would possibly get stack overflow exceptions.

Comment: Is it actually a recursive algorithm, or an iterative algorithm implemented with recursion? My understanding is that TCO can only help with the latter.

Comment: I just want to add that TCO is not `only` an optimization. Supporting it should be part of the language specification, not the compiler/interpreter since code written against one interpreter/compiler with TCO would probably not work on an interpreter/compiler without TCO.

Comment: You can see current support and watch it evolve across engines in Kangax's ES6 compatibility table here: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#proper_tail_calls_(tail_call_optimisation)

Comment: nmichaels: TCO (Tail Call Optimization) is about *any* tail call, not just recursive tail calls.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The ECMAScript 4 specification was originally going to add support for TCO, but it was dropped:

*[No more tail calls in JavaScript?](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3047)*

As of 2010, no widely-available implementations of JavaScript currently do automatic TCO.

---

See comments for more recent updates.

Comment: Just an FYI, Rhino has automatic TCO along with Continuations in "interpreted" mode (opt = -1) http://wiki.apache.org/cocoon/RhinoWithContinuations

Comment: (sorry for trolling) ECMAScript 6 has included TCO, termed Proper Tail Calls in the specification.

Comment: @sclv: What's the trampoline reference?

Comment: The accumulator pattern doesn't accomplish the same effect as TCO. It merely transforms recursive algorithms into tail-recursive form. This is a prerequisite for TCO to be possible, but it is not a substitute for it. You'll still blow the stack in a language that doesn't optimise tail-calls.

Comment: "no widely-available implementations of JS currently do automatic TCO" this is incorrect as of Node 6.2.0, if you pass the right flag

Comment: Tail Call Optimization is supported from ES6

Comment: Second link seems outdated.

Answer (score 26):

No joy for the moment, but thankfully proper tail calls are slated for Harmony (ECMAScript version 6)
http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proper_tail_calls

Comment: @MarkWilbur The question was specifically about _browsers_, not all existing implementations of ECMAScript.

Comment: @UselessCode Nope, this question is about "Javascript engines" so... not just browsers

Comment: @BT There are indeed many non-browser JS environments, and the title does use the more generic "Javascript engines" but the body of the question specifies "...would like to know if any (all?) **browsers** would possibly get stack overflow exceptions."

Comment: I have to counter "but the title says...". I think because he mentions both, the question is about both. But you're right if you're saying it doesn't make the answer obsolete.

Comment: @MarkWilbur As far as I am aware node using the same version of v8 as chrome - which currently doesn't support do TCO
I had a gist with the JS, and the optimised assembler that current V8 produces - https://gist.github.com/mcfedr/832e3553964a014621d5

Comment: @MarkWilbur A simple test shows that an infinitely recursive function in Node v0.12.7 gets `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. Try `node -e 'function x() { x() }; x()'`.

Answer (score 13):

Tail call optimization will be supported In ECMAScript 6 strict mode in the future. Check http://www.2ality.com/2015/06/tail-call-optimization.html for details.

Check http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ for current engine support.

At the moment (18-07-2019) the following engines support tail call optimization:

- Safari >= 10
- iOS >= 10
- Kinoma XS6
- Duktape 2.3

support if "experimental JavaScript features"-flag is turned on:

- Node 6.5
- <s>Chrome 54 / Opera 41</s> Current version of the compat table does not list it anymore

Answer (score 12):

Pretty much every browser you encounter will barf on "too much recursion". Here's an [entry in the V8 bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=457) that will probably be interesting reading.

If it's simple self-recursion, it's probably worth the effort to use explicit iteration rather than hoping for tail-call elimination.

Comment: The bug has finally been accepted. It is under the epic: "Feature Request Harmony". Hopefully that means that they plan to add it to ES6 support in V8.

Comment: You can vote for TCO support in Internet Explorer here: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-internet-explorer-platform/suggestions/6850816-es6-tail-call-optimization

Answer (score 3):

Tail call optimization is now available in [LispyScript](http://lispyscript.com) which compiles to JavaScript. You can read more about it [here](http://lispyscript.blogspot.in/2012/09/loop-recur-and-tail-call-optimization.html).

Comment: What about mutual recursion?

Answer (score 2):

Currently no JavaScript implementations recognise tail recursion. Changes are being made in [ECMAScript 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_-_ECMAScript_2015), and as others have said, there is an open ticket on [V8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript_engine%29).

Here you can see V8's generated assembler for a tail recursion function:

*[Example of how V8 compiles recursion](https://gist.github.com/mcfedr/832e3553964a014621d5)*

Compare that to how [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) has compiled the same function in C

*[Example of C compiler tail recursion](https://gist.github.com/mcfedr/63ad08370d856bad3694)*

V8 retains the recursive call, whereas the C compiler has recognised the tail recursion and changed it into a loop.

Comment: "Currently no JS implementations recognise tail recursion." that is incorrect as of Node 6.2.0, but you gotta pass a flag