# Does JavaScript start a new stack on every recursive call?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I need to perform some recursive operations using JavaScript.

Does JavaScript engine work like Java? For recursion Java starts a new stack on every recursive call. How does JavaScript handle this?

Comment: rel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660577/are-any-javascript-engines-tail-call-optimized

Answer (score 4):

*ECMAscript* has no concept of tail optimization ... yet, if that was the question ?

What does *tail optimization* mean ?

> It means that the stack frame is no longer necessary at the point of
>   the recursive call, and therefore may be eliminated

That in turn means, since there is no official *specification* on that topic, its pretty much up to the interpreter how to handle this. Probably there are some optimizations going on under the hood (V8 ?), but better assume that a JS recursion gets not optimized at all.

Comment: ..and downvoting anonymously isn't helpful at all.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, since it is the correct answer. The standard does not make any guarantee one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every recursive call create a new stack entry

Comment: in javascript ? and in all browser ?.