# Node.js tail-call optimization: possible or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tail-call-optimization

I like JavaScript so far, and decided to use Node.js as my engine partly because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660577/are-any-javascript-engines-tail-call-optimized), which claims that Node.js offers TCO. However, when I try to run this (obviously tail-calling) code with Node.js, it causes a stack overflow:

```
function foo(x) {
    if (x == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return foo(x-1);
    }
}

foo(100000);
```

Now, I did some digging, and I found [this](http://dailyjs.com/2013/10/17/yield/). Here, it seems to say I should write it like this:

```
function* foo(x) {
    if (x == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        yield foo(x-1);
    }
}

foo(100000);
```

However, this gives me syntax errors. I've tried various permutations of it, but in all cases, Node.js seems unhappy with *something*.

Essentially, I'd like to know the following:

1. Does or doesn't Node.js do TCO?
2. How does this magical `yield` thing work in Node.js?

Comment: Run node with the `--harmony` flag to see how your second version works. e.g. `node --harmony mytest.js`. But first re-look at the example you cite, you have only adapted part of it to your case. Regarding TCO the real question is whether V8 has implemented it - and there is no mention of that being done yet in the [v8 changelog](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/ChangeLog) that I can see.

Comment: @barry-johnson: I tried just copying the sample functions using ``yield`` in the second link, and Node.js takes exception to ``function*``. This is one of the reasons why I'm confused.

Comment: That is why I said you need to run node with the --harmony option. Generators are part of ES6/Harmony, which is not the node default.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There are two fairly-distinct questions here:

- Does or doesn't Node.js do TCO?
- How does this magical yield thing work in Node.js?

> **Does or doesn't Node.js do TCO?**

**TL;DR**: **Not anymore, as of Node 8.x**. It did for a while, behind one flag or another, but as of this writing (November 2017) it doesn't anymore because the underlying V8 JavaScript engine it uses doesn't support TCO anymore. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42788286/157247) for more on that.

Details:

Tail-call optimization (TCO) is a required [part of the ES2015 ("ES6") specification](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-tail-position-calls). So supporting it isn't, directly, a NodeJS thing, it's something the V8 JavaScript engine that NodeJS uses needs to support.

As of Node 8.x, V8 doesn't support TCO, not even behind a flag. It may do (again) at some point in the future; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42788286/157247) for more on that.

Node 7.10 down to 6.5.0 at least (my notes say 6.2, but [node.green](http://node.green) disagrees) supported TCO behind a flag (`--harmony` in 6.6.0 and up, `--harmony_tailcalls` earlier) in strict mode only.

If you want to check your installation, here are the tests [node.green](http://node.green) uses (be sure to use the flag if you're using a relevant version):

```
function direct() {
    "use strict";
    return (function f(n){
      if (n <= 0) {
        return  "foo";
      }
      return f(n - 1);
    }(1e6)) === "foo";
}

function mutual() {
    "use strict";
    function f(n){
      if (n <= 0) {
        return  "foo";
      }
      return g(n - 1);
    }
    function g(n){
      if (n <= 0) {
        return  "bar";
      }
      return f(n - 1);
    }
    return f(1e6) === "foo" && f(1e6+1) === "bar";
}

console.log(direct());
console.log(mutual());
```

```
$ # Only certain versions of Node, notably not 8.x or (currently) 9.x; see above
$ node --harmony tco.js
true
true
```

> **How does this magical `yield` thing work in Node.js?**

This is another ES2015 thing ("generator functions"), so again it's something that V8 has to implement. It's completely implemented in the version of V8 in Node 6.6.0 (and has been for several versions) and isn't behind any flags.

Generator functions (ones written with `function*` and using `yield`) work by being able to stop and return an iterator that captures their state and can be used to continue their state on a subsequent occasion. Alex Rauschmeyer has an in-depth article on them [here](http://www.2ality.com/2015/03/es6-generators.html).

Here's an example of using the iterator returned by the generator function explicitly, but you usually won't do that and we'll see why in a moment:

```
"use strict";
function* counter(from, to) {
    let n = from;
    do {
        yield n;
    }
    while (++n < to);
}

let it = counter(0, 5);
for (let state = it.next(); !state.done; state = it.next()) {
    console.log(state.value);
}
```

That has this output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Here's how that works:

- When we call `counter` (`let it = counter(0, 5);`), the initial internal state of the call to `counter` is initialized and we immediately get back an iterator; none of the actual code in `counter` runs (yet).
- Calling `it.next()` runs the code in `counter` up through the first `yield` statement. At that point, `counter` pauses and stores its internal state. `it.next()` returns a state object with a `done` flag and a `value`. If the `done` flag is `false`, the `value` is the value yielded by the `yield` statement.
- Each call to `it.next()` advances the state inside `counter` to the next `yield`.
- When a call to `it.next()` makes `counter` finish and return, the state object we get back has `done` set to `true` and `value` set to the return value of `counter`.

Having variables for the iterator and the state object and making calls to `it.next()` and accessing the `done` and `value` properties is all boilerplate that (usually) gets in the way of what we're trying to do, so ES2015 provides the new `for-of` statement that tucks it all away for us and just gives us each value. Here's that same code above written with `for-of`:

```
"use strict";
function* counter(from, to) {
    let n = from;
    do {
        yield n;
    }
    while (++n < to);
}

for (let v of counter(0, 5)) {
    console.log(v);
}
```

`v` corresponds to `state.value` in our previous example, with `for-of` doing all the `it.next()` calls and `done` checks for us.

Comment: Please could the } and while be on the same line - it seems clearer to me - couldn't edit this - because changing 2 characters is not enough for an edit...

Comment: @AndyS: Pure style edits aren't appropriate in any case.

Answer (score 4):

node.js finally supports TCO since 2016.05.17, [version 6.2.0](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v6.2.0/).

It needs to be executed with the `--use-strict --harmony-tailcalls` flags for TCO to work.

Comment: The linked page doesn't have "tail" or "TCO" on it anywhere, can you link to something that announces tail call support? (The support *is* there, I've checked.) Also note that `--use-strict` is not required to enable it, just `--harmony-tailcalls`.

Comment: Also note that the *reason* it's behind its own flag is that the V8 team do not consider it stable, much less done. They still (as of the V8 in Node v6.2.2) consider it *in progress*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Although not considered stable, so far it works great for me.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: that's the first version to have this flag. The changelog item for it is the upgrade of V8

Answer (score 2):

> 6.2.0 - with 'use strict' and '--harmony_tailcalls'

works only with small tail-optimized recursions of 10000 (like in the question), but fails the function calls itself 99999999999999 times.

> 7.2.0 with 'use strict' and '--harmony'

flag works seamlessly and rapidly even with 99999999999999 calls.

Comment: 99999999999999? That's a lot of calls.. Does it somehow optimize the calculation away?

Answer (score -1):

More concise answer... as of it's date of implementation, as mentioned...

TCO works. It's not bulletproof, but it is very decent. Here's Factorial(7000000,1).

```
>node --harmony-tailcalls -e "'use strict';function f(n,t){return n===1?t:f(n-1,n*t);}; console.log(f(7000000,1))"
Infinity
```

And here it is without TCO.

```
>node -e "'use strict';function f(n,t){return n===1?t:f(n-1,n*t);}; console.log(f(15669,1))"
[eval]:1
function f(n,t){return n===1?t:f(n-1,n*t);}; console.log(f(15669,1))
      ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at f ([eval]:1:11)
at f ([eval]:1:32)
at f ([eval]:1:32)
at ...
```

It does make it all the way to 15668 though.

As for yield, see other answers. Should probably be a separated question.

Comment: Yep. Bumped it by an extra few orders of magnitude just to let the CPU burn.