# node.js and Segmentation fault

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, segmentation-fault, stack-trace

is it possible to inspect the javascript stack trace when `node.js` goes in *Segmentation fault*?

The current situation is the following: I am running a script which has a few nested `async.eachSeries`, which caused for some weird reason a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. Hence, I have increased the stack size via `node --stack-size=1000000` and I am left with the Segmentation fault.

Here is the source code of the script: http://nopaste.info/ca0c118591.html

### Update

I also tried  [`segfault-handler`](https://github.com/ddopson/node-segfault-handler), but for some inscrutable reason it is not catching my segfault.

Comment: You might consider posting your code.

Comment: here is the source code of the script: http://nopaste.info/ca0c118591.html

Comment: Which version of node?

Comment: @zhon: ha, this is an old post. I think the version that was the latest at the 5th of december 2014

Comment: Try rewriting your task so that it calls its callback asynchronously, i.e. instead of `doTask(task, done);` write `doTask(task, function(err, res) { setImmediate(done, err, res); });`.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [`segfault-handler`](https://github.com/ddopson/node-segfault-handler) module which catches segfaults on non-Windows platforms and generates a stack trace. But if you're getting a `RangeError`, that's not a segfault.

Comment: segfault after increasing the stack-size and 'solving' the `RangeError`

Comment: It's very strange. `segfault-handler` correctly handles its own test segmentation fault function `SegfaultHandler.causeSegfault()`, but not my actual bug.

Answer (score 2):

This likely means you have recursivety somewhere in your code. Since V8 removed support for TCO (Tail Call Optimization) the call size will grow until it explodes.

Using `--stack_size` would seem like a natural solution, but it doesn't actually increase the stack size, it is tells V8 to assume there is a bigger stack size when in reality this is controlled by the OS.

Sources:

- https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/5669
- https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/6360
- [Node.js tail-call optimization: possible or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260390/node-js-tail-call-optimization-possible-or-not)

So for now ( with Node.js 8.x ) the best solution is simple to stop using recursive functions.