# Does `tail call optimization` work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, v8

`index.js`:

```
function factorial(n, total) {
  if (n === 1) return total;
  return factorial(n - 1, n * total);
}

console.log(factorial(70000, 1))
```

And I run it like this:

```
node --harmony_tailcalls index.js
```

But it still give me an error:

```
function factorial(n, total) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
              ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

why? I read this [Node.js tail-call optimization: possible or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260390/node-js-tail-call-optimization-possible-or-not) , but still not work.

Comment: Since this is a duplicate of the question TJ answered already, here's the answer that targets your scenario specifically; http://stackoverflow.com/a/39700867/2879498

Comment: The full answer is TJ's definitive answer; http://stackoverflow.com/a/30369729/2879498

Comment: Basically, if you're using Node v6.6.0, you just need the `--harmony` flag, and you need to be using strict mode (`"use strict";`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks! After add `"use strict";` and run `node --harmony index.js`, it seems works. The result is `Infinity`. Is it correct? After I check the call stack. I think it work correct. There is just one my function in the call stack.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder How TCO work in browser? Thanks again!

Comment: @novaline: You'll have to check per browser. Someday, when engines have a mature TCO feature, it'll just be there. For now, if it's there at all, it'll probably be hiding behind a flag you have to enable (if even that's available).