# tail call optimization in javascript does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ecmascript6 introduced tail call optimization(TCO),I wrote the next code

```
'use strict';
var isStrict = (function() { return !this; })();
function add5(a,total=0){
    if(a==1)return total+a;
    return add5(a-1,total+a);
}

add5(100000);
```

and run it both in chrome(57.0.2987.133 (64-bit))

```
<script src="strict.js"></script>
```

and node(v8.1.0).
they all print the result alike:

```
isStrict:true
/data/study/dashboards/api-demo/strict.js:4
function add5(a,total=0){
             ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at add5 (/data/study/dashboards/api-demo/strict.js:4:14)
    at add5 (/data/study/dashboards/api-demo/strict.js:6:12)
    at add5 (/data/study/dashboards/api-demo/strict.js:6:12)
    at add5 (/data/study/dashboards/api-demo/strict.js:6:12)
    at add5 (/data/study/dashboards/api-demo/strict.js:6:12)
    at add5 (/data/study/dashboards/api-demo/strict.js:6:12)
    at add5 (/data/study/dashboards/api-demo/strict.js:6:12)
    at add5 (/data/study/dashboards/api-demo/strict.js:6:12)
    at add5 (/data/study/dashboards/api-demo/strict.js:6:12)
    at add5 (/data/study/dashboards/api-demo/strict.js:6:12)
```

It seems the strict mode is enabled,but tail call optimization does not work,anybody can do me a favor and tell why?

Comment: @Rajesh: I don't think that post is relevant. With TCO working, the stack doesn't grow.

Comment: works for me in Node *v6.9.0* without any flags, but you might want to try `node --harmony`. [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30369729/6567275)

Comment: it seem node v8.1.0 does support TCO from http://node.green/

Answer (score 0):

It seem v8.1.0 does support TCO according http://node.green/
node with version v7.10.x,v7.5.x,v6.11.x may works, and it works find under v7.10.0 with --harmony flag as I tried.

Answer (score 0):

It only works in node with `--harmony_tailcalls` even on version `8.1.0`.

```
function addFive(a, total){
  'use strict';
  if(a < 1) return total;
  return addFive(a-1, total+a);
}

addFive(100000, 0);
```

Comment: thanks,node --v8-options | grep 'harmony' ,TCO is a 'in process' feature in node v8.1.0