# Running out of heap memory when storing WebSocket messages in an array

Tags: node.js, websocket, heap-memory

I'm writing a WebSocket client in Node.js, and I want to perform asynchronous operations with the message data (i.e. storing in database), but also ensure that messages are operated on one at a time, in the order in which they were received.

To achieve this, I'm pushing messages on to an array in my onMessage handler, and simultaneously shifting messages off the array one at a time using a function that calls itself. Something like this:

```
const flushQueue = async () => {

  const nextMessage = messageQueue.shift();

  await doSomethingAsync(nextMessage); // i.e. store in db, etc.

  flushQueue();
}
```

Setting aside the issue of whether or not my system can keep up, this method works well, except the script eventually runs out of heap memory. A simple test reveals that shifting an element off an array actually *increases* the amount of heap memory used, whereas my assumption was that it reduced the memory used:

```
const a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

a.shift();
a.shift();

console.log(process.memoryUsage());
```

Why does removing an element from an array increase the amount of memory used by the process? How can I store my set of queued WebSocket messages in a memory-efficient way, indefinitely?

Answer (score 1):

I am almost sure the problem is in your tail call, and not shifting the array. Node and Javascript does not have proper tail call optimization. Some [stats](https://node.green/) and [post on TCO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260390/node-js-tail-call-optimization-possible-or-not).

Long running loop without tail call optimization will eventually run out of memory.

I would drop this custom queue, and write directly to a database.

SQLite + [better-sqlite3](https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3#when-is-this-library-not-appropriate) driver is a good place to start.

```js
// pseudo-code example (not tested)
ws.on('message', function incoming (data) {
  const stmt = db.prepare('INSERT INTO list(message) VALUES(?)')
  const result = stmt.run(data) // synchronous in-process write
  // do something with result or something else
});
```